# Django: single related object descriptor is deprecated, how can i replace it?

Tags: django

I was following this [guide](https://jeffelmore.org/2010/11/11/automatic-downcasting-of-inherited-models-in-django/), when I arrived to this line:

```
from django.db.models.fields.related import SingleRelatedObjectDescriptor
```

I realized that `SingleRelatedObjectDescriptor` Class has been removed (deprecated) from the module, 
I searched about its deprecation in the documentation, I couldn't find anything helpful, how i can achieve its behaviour now? with what i can replace it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it is mentioned in the [django 1.9 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/1.9/#miscellaneous)

> The related model object descriptor classes in
> django.db.models.fields.related (private API) are moved from the
> related module to related_descriptors and renamed as follows:
>
> - ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor is ForwardManyToOneDescriptor
> - SingleRelatedObjectDescriptor is ReverseOneToOneDescriptor
> - ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor is ReverseManyToOneDescriptor
> - ManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor is ManyToManyDescriptor

So I would assume that you need to do:

`from django.db.models.fields.related_descriptors import ReverseOneToOneDescriptor`

Comment: Thank you, appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help!  .